# Erlang: process staying linked to dead threads

Tags: erlang, hyperlink

I have a process that lots of threads make links to in order to associate themselves with this process. I made the system this way so that at any time I can easily see who is associated to the central process without having to also keep track of any lists inside of the application itself. I can simply do `process_info(self(),links)` and erlang keeps track of which processes are still alive or not, etc....

At least, I thought so, until I found out that the list being returned on this thread isn't accurate at this moment:

```
% P is my central pid
(node@host)212> P.
<0.803.0>

% Get all the links to it
(node@host)213> {links,L} = process_info(P,links).
{links,[<0.29179.155>,<0.6492.250>,<0.29990.293>|...]}

% Counting out all the links
(node@host)214> length(L).
31154

% Filtering out all of the dead processes, put them in Lf
(node@host)215> Lf = lists:filter(fun(Pid) -> try process_info(Pid,links) of {links,_} -> true; _ -> false catch _:_ -> false end end, L).
[<0.29179.155>,<0.6492.250>,<0.29990.293>,<0.23619.530>|...]

% Lf is only about half the size, half the linked processes are dead!
(node@host)216> length(Lf).
15654

% Proof that the links haven't changed in the interim
(node@host)217> {links,L} = process_info(P,links).
{links,[<0.29179.155>,<0.6492.250>,<0.29990.293>|...]}
```

The only thing I can think of that would cause this is network connectivity issues, since some of the links may come from threads on a node on another machine. Is that a possible explanation for this? And is there a way to make the thread clean up its link list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fault. It's actually a problem with how I was checking if processes are dead. process_info doesn't work on threads on remote nodes. D'oh!